# Error creating bean with name 'propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback'

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, websphere, spring-cloud-config

I'm getting a below error when i deploy my spring config server into the IBM WAS 8.5 server.

**Error Stack:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/TransportConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.eclipse.jgit.api.TransportConfigCallback]: Factory method 'propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:620) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1403) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2214) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1293) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83) [na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287) [na:1.8.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:620) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:91) [na:1.8.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257) [na:1.8.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096) [na:1.8.0]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831) [na:1.8.0]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813) [na:1.8.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118) [bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf121726.01]]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.ready(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:132) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1137) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:750) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:446) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1137) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.eclipse.jgit.api.TransportConfigCallback]: Factory method 'propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:161) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.ssh.SshUriProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$905bf655.isIgnoreLocalSshSettings(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.TransportConfiguration.propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback(TransportConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.TransportConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e312d175.CGLIB$propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.TransportConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e312d175$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c338ed79.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.TransportConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e312d175.propertiesBasedSshTransportCallback(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodConstraintViolationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243) ~[bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf121726.01]]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:850) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:829) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134) ~[bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf121726.01]]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf121726.01]]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf121726.01]]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf121726.01]]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf121726.01]]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809) ~[na:na]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
```

**Background:**

***Spring-boot --> 1.5.9,*
*Spring-cloud-dependencies --> Edgware.SR2***

Using Spring-cloud-config dependency, i had created web application i.e. Spring config server. In this web app i have starter class like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.out.println("Hello world !!");
        return application.sources(ConfigStarter.class);
    }
}
```

Since i need to deploy this into the WebsphereApplicationServer WAS 8.5, used 'SpringBootServletInitializer' and overridden 'configure' method and returned the starter class.

Also added start-class properties pointing to starter class in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <start-class>com.product.config.ConfigStarter</start-class>
</properties>
```

**Here is my POM.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.common.product</groupId>
        <artifactId>config-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>pt-config-service-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>pt-config-service-web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>com.product.config.ConfigStarter</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>IBM</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>8.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Edgware.SR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/.copyarea.db</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Parent POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.common.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>config-service</name>
    <modules>
        <module>config-service-ear</module>
        <module>config-service-web</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Now, coming to the issue part:**

- When i use Tomcat (Embedded server), it works perfectly fine.
- With the same source code,   bundled with EAR & deploy it into WAS 8.5,

  1. Without **@EnableConfigServer** annotation, application starts and I can access all the rest endpoints, actuator endpoints, etc.
  2. With **@EnableConfigServer** annotation, WAS server failed to start with above error stack.

Can anyone help me out on this?. Am i missing any dependency?